# Can variables be used in elasticsearch index templates?

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana

I have a variety of elasticsearch indices which are created daily by logstash with the format:

```
"logstash-%{cluster_type}-%{cluster_name}-jobaccounting-v2-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
```

I would like to create an alias in elasticsearch which drops the version number from the index name. I am planning to point my kibana instance at the aliased index rather than the versioned index so that I can change the version numbers without impacting kibana.

```
index: "logstash-%{cluster_type}-%{cluster_name}-jobaccounting-v2-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"

alias: "logstash-%{cluster_type}-%{cluster_name}-jobaccounting-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
```

Elasticsearch index templates can be used to create an alias everytime a new index is created. 
https://www.elastic.co/blog/aliases-ftw

Unfortuantely, I have not found any good way to use variables in the alias name. I would like to avoid having to create a template for every cluster_type, cluster_name, and date.

If I had 2 entries for each variable cluster_name and cluster_type, I would have 4 indices every day, which would require 4 aliases for each day.

If I could use a date variable, then I could just have 4 templates rather than 4 templates for each day.

Is there a way to use a date variable in the alias name? Does taking this approach make sense?

Answer (score 0):

The only available placeholder is {index}, so you can't compose more complex alias name inside template.
https://www.elastic.co/blog/aliases-ftw