# Elasticsearch Opendistro ISM: What approach can be taken to apply the rollover alias and policy to new indices, automatically?

Tags: elasticsearch, ilm, ism, index-management

When ISM policies are used, the index policy settings need to be applied during index creation but those settings are lost once a new index is created from the rollover action applied by a certain stage/phase in the policy.

For instance, having indices in the form:

```
pattern:        msp-*          [* => number, in the index template]
alias:          msp-*-alias    [applied during the index creation]
rollover alias: msp-*-alias
policy:         msp-policy-id
```

Having a template index pattern `msp-*` (where * is a number) impedes having a rollover alias msp-*-alias for each value that * can take applied automatically. How could this situation be approached?

**References:**

[Can variables be used in elasticsearch index templates?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36288714/can-variables-be-used-in-elasticsearch-index-templates#)

https://discuss.elastic.co/t/index-lifecycle-management-dynamic-rollover-alias-and-template-name/169614

https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/20367

https://github.com/opendistro-for-elasticsearch/index-management/issues/95

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticsearch-service/latest/developerguide/ism.html

Comment: In ISM policy rollover alias does not change after rollover. For example after multiple rollover you will have msp-000001, msp-000002, msp-000003 indices are there. While all indices should point to single static alias like msp-alias. Alias does not change after rollover.

Answer (score 1):

In ISM policy alias does not change after rollover. For example after multiple rollover you will have `msp-000001, msp-000002, msp-000003` indices are there. While all indices should point to single static alias like `msp-alias`. Alias does not change after rollover.

Index setting would be applicable by template while creation of the index through rollover. Below is the example of index template.

```
PUT _template/msp_template
{
  "index_patterns": "msp-*",
    "settings": {
      "number_of_shards": 2,
      "number_of_replicas": 1,
    "index": {
      "opendistro.index_state_management.rollover_alias": "msp-alias"
    }
  }
}
```